# Pandas - how to pass variable as column into nested loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a nested loop that I'm trying to pass values from a list into, but it will not recognize the list value. If I replace the `value[col]` with any list value like `value['OpNo']` it works. Is there a specific wrapper or something I need around either the list values or the assignment code?

I tried the lists like `col_list = ["'OpNo'", "'StationNo'", "'Spindle'", "'OpDescription'"]` and wrapping the `col` callout like `value[[col]]`

The code below is getting the following exception: `KeyError: 'OpNo'`

```
row_indexer = 0
col_indexer = 1
iloc_indexer = 0
count_row = operationData.shape[0]
col_list = ['OpNo', 'StationNo', 'Spindle', 'OpDescription']
while row_indexer < count_row:    
    value = operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],[iloc_indexer]]
    for col in col_list:
        value = value[col].values[0]
        wb['OneOpSheet'].cell(row = (row_indexer + 12), column = (col_indexer + 1)).value = value
        col_indexer = (col_indexer + 1)
    row_indexer = (row_indexer + 1)
    iloc_indexer = (iloc_indexer + 1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample or dtypes listing from operationData?  You can use `operationData.dtypes` for the info listing.  Also `row_indexer = (row_indexer + 1)` and similar calls can be replaced by `row_indexer += 1`.

Comment: I just checked `operationData.dtypes`, every column is an object. And thanks for the `+=` tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help you exactly, but maybe it'll get you in the right direction.  You can use Pandas.DataFrame.itertuples() to run across all rows in your dataframe, picking off values as you need them.

I went a bit further and created a quick column label dictionary to help sync the nested loops.

I tried to comment where necessary, but if you don't understand something, let me know!

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook(filename='./generic_workbook_name.xlsx')

# Created smoe data for a dataframe.
fake_data_dict = {
    'OpNo':['1','2','3','4',],
    'StationNo':['11','22','33','44',],
    'Spindle':['S1','S2','S3','S4',],
    'OpDescription':['This','is','a','description',]
    }

# Create the dataframe.
data = pd.DataFrame(fake_data_dict)
```

Our dataframe:

```
  OpNo StationNo Spindle OpDescription
0    1        11      S1          This
1    2        22      S2            is
2    3        33      S3             a
3    4        44      S4   description
```

The rest of the script:

```
col_list = ['OpNo','StationNo','Spindle','OpDescription']


# Create a column label dictionary; Add 1 to index for Excel cells
col_dict = {i+1:v for i, v in enumerate(col_list)}

# Iterate over each row
for idx, row in enumerate(data.itertuples(), start = 1):
    # For each key in our column dictionary [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for key in col_dict.keys():
        print('Row: {a}\n\tColumn: {b}\n\t\tValue: {c}'.format(a = idx, b = key,
                                                               # Reduce the index by 1; Get column name based on key value.
                                                               c = data.loc[idx - 1, col_dict[key]]))
```

Output:

```
Row: 1
    Column: 1
        Value: 1
Row: 1
    Column: 2
        Value: 11
Row: 1
    Column: 3
        Value: S1
Row: 1
    Column: 4
        Value: This
Row: 2
    Column: 1
        Value: 2
Row: 2
    Column: 2
        Value: 22
Row: 2
    Column: 3
        Value: S2
Row: 2
    Column: 4
        Value: is
Row: 3
    Column: 1
        Value: 3
Row: 3
    Column: 2
        Value: 33
Row: 3
    Column: 3
        Value: S3
Row: 3
    Column: 4
        Value: a
Row: 4
    Column: 1
        Value: 4
Row: 4
    Column: 2
        Value: 44
Row: 4
    Column: 3
        Value: S4
Row: 4
    Column: 4
        Value: description
```

With that in mind, this could simplify your script:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(data.itertuples(), start = 1):
    for key in col_dict.keys():
        wb['OneOpSheet'].cell(row = (idx + 11), column = (key + 1)).value = data.loc[idx - 1, col_dict[key]]
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I am not familiar with enumerate or iterturples. I'm trying to get more pythonic with my code but still default to looping the old way a lot. I could see how this was useful though, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: This is fantastic. Much more elegant than what I came up with. I don't fully understand the enumerate with intertuples yet but it gives me something to read into. Thank you!  Much better than my solution

Answer (score 0):

I think `value = operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],[iloc_indexer]]` returns a dataframe. Try `value = value.loc[col].values[0]`.

Comment: This returned `KeyError: "the label [OpNo] is not in the [index]"`, I tried adding the extra " " around the list values but got the same exception but with `['OpNo']`

Comment: In that case, it would seem to me that `operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],[iloc_indexer]]` returns a single value with no key. In that case drop the iloc indexer and replace with `operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],:]`.I am not really sure why you are using an iloc indexer in the first place.

Comment: The idea was I had a 1 x 4 df that I then turned to a 1x1 df using `value = operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],[iloc_indexer]]`, but I want to use that single value not as a df later, hence the `value = value[col].values[0]` to capture the value itself

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have both commands inside the `for` loop and reset a couple of the indexers after that finished. The below nested loop accomplishes what I needed:

```
while row_indexer < count_row:    
    for col in col_list:
        value = operationData.iloc[[row_indexer],[iloc_indexer]]
        value = value[col].values[0]
        wb['OneOpSheet'].cell(row = (row_indexer + 12), column = (col_indexer + 2)).value = value
        col_indexer += 1
        iloc_indexer += 1
    row_indexer += 1
    iloc_indexer = 0
    col_indexer = 0
```

Comment: See my edited comment. I pdated the dictionary and indexing to accommodate Excel cells, but if you run the function it will print each row, column, and cell value to help visualize the output and better optimize your script.